# Remove child elements from Parent with filter operation in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, filter

I want to filter nested list data with the deletion of child items which are not matched. 
you can see the kotlin playground example here https://pl.kotl.in/b-6SOvMvZ

```
val filterTxt = "an"
val filterData = mainData.deviceList.filter { items -> 
    items.itemList.any { 
          it.itemName.contains(filterTxt, true)
    }
}
```

Currently using any with filter but not getting expected result as it returns all items.

```
Current Result : [[fan, mobile], [bottle, mobile, fan]]

Expected Result : [[fan], fan]]
```

Answer (score 1):

`any` will return true if any given element of the list fulfills the predicate. That's not what you want. You want only the elements that fulfill your condition (or predicate).

```
val filterData = mainData.deviceList.map { items -> 
    items.itemList.filter { 
        it.itemName.contains(filterTxt, true)
    }
}
```